# Aspose QR code not showing in report server

Tags: reporting-services, aspose

I'm trying to get QR code working in Microsoft reporting server with Aspose.barcode software but no success.

First of all I installed the assemblies on the report server and and development machine.
Added a reference to System.Drawing.dll and Aspose.BarCode.ReportingServices
Added a classname below that: Aspose.BarCode.ReportingServices.BarCodeBuilder
Added instance name objBarCode

In the code section of the report I added the function:

```
Function GetBarCodeImageOfQRCode(s as String)
  objBarCode.QREncodeMode = 0
  objBarCode.SymbologyType = 17179869184
  objBarCode.CodeText = s

  return objBarCode.GenerateBarCodeImage()
End Function
```

Then added an Image control to the report and in the expression on what image to use I did:

`=Code.GetBarCodeImageOfQRCode("Test")`

No errors on save but no QR image appears on the report when running it.

What do I need to do to get aspose barcode working in report server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code in a way that it should convert Bitmap to byte array and try to set the correct mime type. Following is the code snippet that can be used.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap objBitMap = objBarCode.GenerateBarCodeImage()
Dim bitmapData As Byte() = Nothing

Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
      objBitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
      bitmapData = ms.ToArray()
End Using

Return bitmapData
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: The length of the data returned is 24246 bytes so the object seems to work. I've changed the mimetype to image/bitmap but still no image shows up in the image box, only a red cross

Comment: aha! it works now, after changing the source of the image to database too. This saved me lots of hours of trial and error, so thanks!

Comment: Good to know that the issue has been resolved. Thanks